# Сложить массивы строк

Tags: c, строки, visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2010

Добрый день. Есть 3 массива строк.  В третий массив(с) нужно сложить массивы a и b через пробел. Как это можно сделать?

```
 strcat_s(c[k], a[j]);
 strcat_s(c[k], b[j]);
```

Я сделал это так, но vs выдаёт ошибку
Полный код программы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 1000

int main()
{int k=0,n,d;
int t[N];
char a[N][20],b[N][20],c[N][40];
scanf("%d %d",&n,&d);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){scanf("%s %s %d",&a[i][20],&b[i][20],&t[i]);}
if (n>1){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(int j=1; j<n; j++){
    if ((a[i][20]==b[j][20])&&(b[i][20]=a[j][20])){
       if ((t[j]-t[i]>0)&&(t[j]-t[i]<=d))
        {
        k++;
        strcat(c[k], a[j]);
        strcat(c[k], b[j]);
       }
    }
       }
    }
}
else {k=0;};
printf("%d\n",k);
for (int i=1; i<k+1; i++){sprintf("%s\n",c[i]);}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: использование C-строк критично?

Comment: Нет, не критично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
...
vector<string> a, b, c;
...
c[i] = a[i] + " " + b[i]; // В цикле
```

Answer (score 1):

```
snprintf (a,sizeof(a),"%s %s",b,c);
```

Это, конечно, склеить 2 строки через пробел.
Опишите, как у Вас организованы массивы для более подробного ответа.

Comment: Прикрепил полный код программы

Comment: Если правильно понял у Вас 3 массива (a, b, c) каждый из N строк, каждая строка максимум 20 байт (1 байт на завершающий '\0' итого до 19 символов в строке). 

Вы вводите n штук (n < N) в a[i], b[i] и t[i] (какое-то число), а затем в зависимости от некого условия хотите получить в c[i] b[i] пробел c[i]. **ТАК ?**

1. Ошибка при вводе в scanf(). Надо 

    scanf ("%s %s %d",&a[i][0], &b[i][0], &t[i]);

Но на практике так вводить нельзя (возможно переполнение).

2. Конкатенацию a[k] и b[k] запишите

    spnrintf (&c[k][0],20,"%s %s", &a[k][0], &b[k][0]);

Вообще тут все просто, думаете об адреса